# React and node Cross origin error using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors, axios

This is my node js server and i am trying to consume this api in my react app but it showing me cors error except adding cors in my node js server.

```
const connectDB = require('./config/connectDB');
const studentController = require('./routes/api/studentController');
const competitionRouter = require('./routes/api/competitionRouter');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();


//database Connection
connectDB();
//set a middleware to parse data


app.use(express.json());

 app.use('/api/students',studentController);
 app.use('/api/competitions',cors(),competitionRouter);

app.listen(5000);
```

[Error of cross-origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euiBZ.png)

This is my code for the react here i am trying to store values coming form the api to the state variable to show it in code but i am getting above error i tried all things but i can't find anything.

```
import './CompetitionList.css';
import {Button, TabContainer} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class CompetitionList extends Component {
    state={
        competitions:[]
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.onchangeLocation( "Home");

        axios.get('localhost:5000/api/competitions')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({competitions:data});
        })
    }
    render() {
        //const competitionlist = ['competition1','competition2','competition3','competition4','competition5','competition6','competition7','competition8','competition9'];
        return (
            <div>
                <TabContainer>
                    <Col>
                    <Row>
                    <Button className="addcompetition" variant="success">Add Competition</Button>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                {/* {
                    this.state.competitions.map(comp => {
                        return <Card className="card" style={{ width: '21rem' }}>
                        <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{comp.title}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>
                        Competition Description
                        </Card.Text>
                        <Button variant="primary">Go</Button>
                        </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    })
                } */}
                </Row>
                </Col>
                </TabContainer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add `htpp` in your URL. like this `http://localhost:5000/api/competitions` and have a look there I hope it's helpful `https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node`

Comment: Thank you so much i was trying to find solution everywhere. now i am mad i was struggling because of just one http://.

Comment: welcome @Y.m Patel

Answer (score -1):

Use this Extension it might help you with above problem.
https://webbrowsertools.com/test-cors/